# redux-form not calling onSubmit on form

Tags: redux-form

I am seriously getting fed up with redux-form. This is the latest problem/bug that I have :

For some reason if I use the Field in my form the default onSubmit on my form is disabled.

The following prints the alert :

```
class CustomerPage2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <form id="myform" onSubmit={() => alert("redux form is soooo much fun")} >
                <input type="text" id="abc"/>
            </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'customerRegistration',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true
})(CustomerPage2);
```

However if I add a Field to my form the onSubmit in my form DOES NOT WORK.

The following does not work (Input is just a simple presentation component) :

```
class CustomerPage2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <form id="myform" onSubmit={() => alert("redux form is so much fun")} >
                <input type="text" id="abc"/>
                <Field
                    className={'setup__input input'}
                    name={'salutation'}
                    mandatory={true}
                    placeholder={'Mr/Mrs/Ms/Miss'}
                    component={Input}
                />
            </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'customerRegistration',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true
})(CustomerPage2);
```

Why would submit suddenly disable if I use Fields in my component? I don't understand why it would do this.

I'm literally exahausted by the 'magic' that happens in the background in redux-forms. This is the last straw before I try some other library.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have you set `destroyOnUnmount` and `forceUnregisterOnUnmount`? Is this form part of a wizard? Have you tried `onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}` and then moving your alert to `reduxForm({ onSubmit: () => { alert(); } });`?

Comment: I think it is the same problem of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086825/redux-form-will-not-submit-if-more-than-one-field/54120218#54120218.  All you need to submit is using the "handleSubmit" function ( redux-form adds it to the component props) and a submit button